# Error al conetar base de datos php

Tags: php, mysqli

Hola buenas tardes tengo un error con mi sistema es que estoy cambiando a PHP 5.6 a 7.1 me da ese error cuando quiero conectar mi base de datos y no tengo idea de porque aquí dejo el código fuente

```
@$conectar = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword);

// check the connection
if (!$conectar){
die(include ("500.php"));
}


/* User datos */

$bdselect = mysqli_select_db($dbdatabase,$conectar);

if (!$bdselect) { 
die(include ("500.php"));
}
```

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\conectarbd.php on line 17
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: bdselect in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\conectarbd.php on line 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta linea `$bdselect = mysqli_select_db($dbdatabase,$conectar);` la variable `$conectar` debe ir como primer argumento. Eso te dice el error `expects parameter 1 to be mysqli` pero le estas mandando un string `$dbdatabase`

Comment: tengo otro error me puedes ayudar `Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in`

Comment: publica otra pregunta con ese error